# Sampling from Bayesian posterior without a tractable prior

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian, sampling, bayesian-network

Let's say that we have a Bayesian network that looks like this:

**A** -> **B** -> **C**

Obviously this network is fully specified by the set of conditional and unconditional probability density/mass functions:

P(**A**), P(**B|A**), P(**C|B**)

Now, let's say that we have observed that **C** takes on some value *c*. In light of this evidence, we want to obtain samples from the posterior distribution of **B** conditioned on **C** = *c*.

In order to do this in a Metropolis-style way, we're required to evaluate the prior probability of **B** when we calculate the acceptance probability, which requires us to evaluate the integral: $$\int P(B|A)P(A)dA$$

But what if this integral is intractable? Then we can't evaluate the prior probability of **B**. We could probably estimate it, using more Monte Carlo methods (since we could generate samples from P(**A,B**) using P(**A**) and P(**B|A**)), but that seems inefficient.

How can we sample from P(**B|C**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be sampling from the prior $P(A, B)$ but the posterior $P(A, B | C)$, by for example using
$$
P(A, B | C ) \propto P(C | B) P(B | A) P(A),
$$
in a Metropolis-Hastings or some other approach. Now assuming you can do this and you set up your Markov chain you will have samples $(A_i, B_i) \sim P(A, B | C)$ and you can then estimate any functional you like of the variable $B$ by just ignoring the samples of $A$, now sure that does seem somewhat inefficient, but that inefficiency is the price you have paid for avoiding the intractable integral and it is often a price worth paying!

To clarify if you are interested in some statistic $f(B)$ then you can write it as a function of both variables, $f(a, b) = f(b)$ say, then you set up the Markov chain and then use your sample to estimate
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} f(A_i,B_i) \rightarrow &\int_\mathcal{B} \int_{\mathcal{A}} f(a, b) p(a,b|c)dadb  \\
&=\int_\mathcal{B} f(b) \left( \int_{\mathcal{A}} p(a,b|c) da \right) db \\
&= \int_{\mathcal{B}} f(b) \, p(b|c)db = \mathbb{E}_{B \sim P(B|C)}\left[ f(B) \right].
\end{align}
$$
Finally worth mentioning that the attractiveness of sampling methods is how easy they are to set up and produce some output - it can be more challenging to assess questions regarding convergence of that output, and there are alternatives to sampling methods with their own particular pros and cons.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot that we can do that.

You mention challenges with assessing the convergence of the output. Are you referring to typical MCMC problems such as deciding on a burn-in period or hyperparameters? If not, could you point me in a direction as to what texts I could consult to gain a better understanding on sampling methods?